# I lost a MacBook Pro Retina 2013, What should I do to locate it?

Tags: icloud, macbook-pro, find-my-mac

I forgot it in the train station in a backpack.

The Mac is locked with a password. It has Mavericks installed.

Find my mac is enabled. What should I do to locate it and avoid thieve disable "find my Mac" feature somehow.

I don't know if I should enable "Lock" or "Erase Mac" in iCloud.

Thanks

Comment: is there a sticker on it so some decent person can contact you to return it? if not send your self a message with finders fee and your phone number.

Comment: No, my name is not in any place of the backpack. Also, I don't know how to send this message. Anyway, how will this person read the message if my session is locked with a password?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to locate it is via find my mac.

When it is a personal mac my advice is to lock it in iCloud.
When the mac is used for business, best thing to do is to erase the mac.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a PhD student. Is not confidential data.

Answer (score 0):

[Apple recommends:](https://www.apple.com/icloud/find-my-iphone.html)

Just sign in at iCloud.com or use the Find My iPhone app to see your missing iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, or Mac on a map. And with the Lost Mode feature you don’t just see where your device is, you can track where it’s been. That way you can decide on your best course of action.

You can immediately lock your device and send it a message with a contact number.

Then whoever finds it can call you from the Lock screen without accessing the rest of the information on your device.

I have a sticker on my devices with a phone number so who ever find it can call me. There is a lot of honest people.